# Pivot With Calendar Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I am trying to pivot this data but I am getting an error of

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

Highlighting the comma after `SUM([Total Count])` but it has to be there, what should I change so my query executes properly?

```
select *
FROM
(
  select a.regionalLocale As [RL], 
  Count(ID) As [Total Count], 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dt.week) AS Week
  FROM database14.dataTable a
  INNER JOIN calendarDB.masterCalendar dt
  ON a.SaleDate = dt.FullDate
  WHERE a.SaleDate IS NOT NULL
) src
pivot
(
  SUM([Total Count]), [RL]
  For Week IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13])
) piv
```

Comment: What's `, [RL]` after the `sum([total..)`?

Comment: The alias for regionalLocale in the query above

Comment: You can't pivot on multiple columns like that.  What do you expect the final result to be?  Did you try removing that?

Comment: Going vertically down left side I want to show a.regionalLocale, horizontally across the top I want to show Week, and the data portion of things I want to show Count(ID)

Comment: Right, did you try removing that `, RL`?

Comment: a different error of regionallocale is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Change `Count(ID)` to just be `id` inside the subquery and then change `SUM([Total Count])` to `count(id)` for the PIVOT.  You don't need to aggregate inside your subquery, let the pivot do ti

Comment: @bluefeet That did it!!!! If you want to answer, I will accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few issues with your query.

One you've got the syntax `SUM([Total Count]), [RL]` in your PIVOT. You only want to include the column you are aggregating here.

Second, there is no need to use `count(id)` inside your subquery, let the PIVOT aggregation handle the total.  Change your code to:

```
select [RL], 
  [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13]
FROM
(
  select a.regionalLocale As [RL], 
    ID, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), dt.week) AS Week
  FROM database14.dataTable a
  INNER JOIN calendarDB.masterCalendar dt
    ON a.SaleDate = dt.FullDate
  WHERE a.SaleDate IS NOT NULL
) src
pivot
(
  COUNT(ID)
  For Week IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13])
) piv
```